# Flask-admin: How to do an action after inline editing a field

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have the following object (table) defined:

**models.py**

```
class vendors_rfi(db.Model):
    vendor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('vendors.vendorid'), primary_key = True, nullable = False, autoincrement = False)
    update_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, autoincrement = False, default = datetime.datetime.now)
    status = db.Column(db.String(1), nullable = False, autoincrement = False)
    current_round = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False, autoincrement = False)
```

Then, I add the view:

**main.py**

```
class vendors_rfi_view(ModelView):
    form_base_class = FlaskForm
    column_list = [vendors.vendor_name, 'status', 'current_round', 'update_date']
    column_editable_list = ['status', 'current_round']
    edit_modal = True
    form_choices = {
        'status': [('E', 'E'), ('R', 'R'), ('N', 'N')],
        'current_round': [('0', '0'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2')]}
```

Now I am allowed to inline edit Status and Current Round (see screenshot).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNeVr.png)

However, how do I do to autoupdate the column Update Date to datetime.datetime.now() after Status or Current Round is changed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a line like this to have a timestamp set on an update on the model:

update_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate = datetime.utcnow)

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
I actually used datetime.datetime.now instead though :D